# Java resource clean up before object destruction

Tags: java, sql, database, destructor, resource-cleanup

I've the following problem and I know there are already a lot of questions but none of these give me really a satisfactorily answer! I wrote a lot of stuff in C++ and this language provide a destructor, Java doesn't because of the garbage collection.

A little introduction in my situation: I wrote a software which is accessing a local Sqlite3 database. I wrote a central singleton class for accessing this database. Multiple other classes access the DB through this wrapper class. Here is the pseudo-code of this wrapper class:

```
public class MyDbWrapper
{
    private currentDbConnection;

    public MyDbWrapper(dbPath)
    {
        // Open the database connection with given path
    }

    public readFromDb()
    {
        ... // Uses the class member currentDbConnection
    }

    public writeToDb()
    {
        ... // Uses the class member currentDbConnection
    }

    public closeDb()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how could I ensure that the database connection is closed before quitting the application? Yes I already implemented the `AutoCloseable` interface and yes I worked already a lot with `try-with-resources`, but because of the access by multiple classes this isn't really an option!
In C++ a destructor would solve this issue, but the possible "equivalent" in java the method `finalize` is **deprecated**!

So are there any other options or should I totally re-design my complete wrapper? If yes, how could I prevent performance issues because of a lot of read write access if I re-open the database every time?

Comment: You probably should not keep that connection open so long

Comment: @Lino Okay but this means that I must re-open the connection every time before read or write to database?! Isn't this a big performance problem with a higher rate of I/O access?

Comment: Thinking that there may be performance issue is not something you should base your decision on. Try to benchmark it, and see if it makes a *big* difference opening and closing the connection every time, or just keep the connection open

Comment: You write in the `main()` a `try-with` that creates one `MyDbWrapper` and then does all of the work inside. On exit, the wrapper will be closed.

Comment: Your program MUST start to run in some main() function. Simply wrap that with try-finally, and close everything there.

Comment: @Lino If this DB is not shared with other applications, there is no much reason not to just open the connection at the start and then close it at the end.

Comment: @Joker_vD Oh okay that's a very good idea I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Joker_vD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440433/joker-vd) already said, I solved this issue by using a try-with-resources statement in the main method of my program...

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    try(MyDbWrapper wrapper = new MyDbWrapper())
    {
        // Execute other task with usage of the database wrapper
    }
}
```

With this solution there is no need for a desturctor or the usage of the deprecated method `finalize()`, the database connection get closed if program ends...

**Thanks again and credits to [Joker_vD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440433/joker-vd)**